# Show that $T: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear if and only if $T(iz) = iTz$ for all z

Tags: complex-analysis

Just a question about complex vs real linearity. The problem is to show that $T: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear if and only if $T(iz) = iTz$ for all z.

So far, I understand that some relation T is $\mathbb{R}$-linear if $T(m \vec{v} \pm n \vec{u}) = mT(\vec{v}) \pm nT(\vec{u})$ for $m, n \in \mathbb{R}$ and it’s $\mathbb{C}$-linear if the same thing is true for $m, n \in \mathbb{C}$.

I’m not really sure where to go from here. I found $iz = -z_2 + iz_1$, but I’m not sure how to use the definitions of linearity here. Thanks in advance.

Edited to fix awful LaTeX, sorry

Comment: What is $CC$, what is $RR$, what is $T$?

Comment: Use `\mathbb{C}` for $\mathbb{C}$, `\vec{v}` for $\vec{v}$ and `\in` for $\in$.

Comment: What you found (one line before the last one) doesn't make much sense if you don't specify what $\;z,\,z_1,\,z_2\;$ are, since that equality is clearly false for *general* $\;z,z_1,z_2\in\Bbb C\;$

Answer (score 1):

A simple counter-example is $T(z)=|z|$. Unless you assume that $T$ is already real linear you cannot prove this.